# Report viewer for crystal report in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I want to display crystal report in report viewer in my mvc application, I have seen many report viewer controls for mvc for rdl files, Is there any package for crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

No. Crystal reports is not supported in ASP.net MVC. You have to use Web forms. However, if you absolutely have to, you can combine both approaches, by using controllers for collecting parameters and getting the best of MVC, and then serve the report page (.aspx) either with an embedded iFrame, or redirecting to the report.

Web forms supports friendly URLs to serve pages without extensions, so this can "mordernise" your implementation and keep the entire application consistent.

SAP publishes information on [installing the prerequisites](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) and the [API guide](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+for+Visusl+Studio+.NET+SDK).

Comment: how do we pass parameter values to crystal report and generate report when using reportviewer control ?

Comment: after adding a reportviewer control to your page, in your code behind you can access it by name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786283/474702 for example